# CRIU Installation on Linux Kernel 3.10 or lower:

Tags: linux-kernel, openvz

CRIU tool(http://criu.org/Installation) mentions that it requires Linux Kernel 3.11 or newer. I am working on a Linux kernel 3.10 which cannot be updated to 3.11 because of some requirements and I require it to be installed in this lower version of Linux.

I have looked into different blogs but could not find it addressed anywhere. Also, criu website has not mentioned anything about how to install it on lower version Kernel or any patches for the same.

So, Can you please share any solution which can help me solve this issue or any patches which can be applied to install it in the lower kernel version.

Comment: What are the requirements that prevent updating to 3.11?

Comment: My code is in final phase and there are modules that are designed specifically in accordance with 3.10, so updating will not be feasible at this moment and its a bit urgent. 

Or please suggest if there is any other tool with similar functionality and which works with Linux 3.10.

I have already looked into other tools DMTCP and Cryopid but these    didnt serve the purpose.

Answer (score 1):

All required commits are here http://criu.org/Upstream_kernel_commits

Answer (score 0):

Just backport all the necessary changes from 3.11 to 3.10.
(And no, nobody knows which ones, or how many, these would be.)

It would be easier to move your own code to 3.11.